# Cannot convert from 'Program.state<TState>' to 'Program.state<object>' passing custom type to class in a dictionnary

Tags: c#, winforms, class, types

I'm working on a lightweight state system for my app.

I'm kinda confused:
how can I pass type to my class in a dictionary?

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Program
{
    public class state<TState>
    {
        private TState? _value;
        public TState Value { get { return _value; } set { if (!_value.Equals(value)) _value = value;if(onChange != null ) onChange(Value); } }
        private Action<TState>? onChange;
        public  state(TState val, Action<TState>? action)
        {
            _value = val;
            onChange = action;
        }

    }
    public class stateHolder
    {
        
        public Dictionary<string, object>  states = new();
        public void AddState<TState>(string name, TState value, Action<TState>? onChange)
        {
            state<TState> state = new state<TState>(value, onChange);
            states[name] = state;//ERROR HERE
        }
        public object? this[string stateName] { get{ return states[stateName];} }

    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        stateHolder states = new();
        states.AddState<string>("test","Yeah",(x)=>Console.WriteLine(x));
        state<string> test = states["test"] as state<string>;
        test.Value = "Hey";//should console log Hey 
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        test.Value = "Hello";//should console log Hey 
    }
}
```

I'm not a beginner, but not a pro at all. I code when I have freetimes so sorry if my code is dumb if you can help me would be nice thanks in advance links bottom

Fiddle link https://dotnetfiddle.net/GxdLGb
Collab link https://dotnetfiddle.net/GxdLGb#&togetherjs=G2ED70iyE8

Comment: Primarily because `typeof(state<TState>).BaseType != typeof(state<object>)`, but instead `typeof(state<TState>).GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(state<>)`. You can work around the problem, either with `Dictionary<string, object>` or by introducting a non-generic interface `Dictionary<string, Istate>`.

Comment: i tried to use object instead of state<object> problem i need to call value like `state<string> test = states["test"] as state<string>;
  test.Value = "Hey";//should console log Hey `

Comment: I've updated fiddle and it's works, but i found it tricky

Comment: To access `TState Value`, the caller must use an api that allows them to specify the generic parameter. You could return the instance so the caller can keep track of it; `state<TState> AddState<TState>(`, but if you put instances with different types into the same dictionary, it's hard for the caller to know which type they are manipulating. Unless you can encapsulate that behaviour into a non-generic interface.